# If $U_a = \{a n^2 - 1 : n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is a topological basis on $\Bbb{Z}$ then $U_a$ is clopen?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

Let $P = $ the prime numbers in $\Bbb{N}$.  Define $P^i = \{ \pm q_1 \cdots q_i : q_j \in P\}$.  These sets $\{ P^j\}_{j\geq 0}$ with $P^0 := \{\pm 1\}, P^{-1} := \{0\}$ form a basis for a topological space on $\Bbb{Z}$ turning it into a topological monoid.

The basis sets $P^i$ are both open and closed since each equals $\Bbb{Z} \setminus (\biguplus\limits_{i\neq j=-1}^{\infty} P^j)$.

Now let the [open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482435/basis-for-a-topology-on-bbbz-using-u-a-an2-1-n-in-bbbz) be unions of sets of the form $U_a = \{ a n^2  - 1 : n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.  If $a' = b^2 a$ then $U_{a'} \subset U_{a}$.  Conversely if every $a'n^2 - 1$ is of the form $am^2 - 1$ then for $n = 1$ we have $a' = am^2$.

Thus I have proved that $U_b \subset U_a$ if and only if $b = am^2$ for some $m \in \Bbb{Z}$.  I don't know if that helps, but my question is:

> Can we write each $U_a$ as a closed set as well?

*(Note. Thanks to commenter we can only ask the question on the space $\Bbb{Z}\setminus \{-1\}$.  In other words consider the subspace topology on $X = \Bbb{Z}\setminus \{-1\}$ generated by $\{U_a \cap X\}_{a\in \Bbb{Z}}$.)*

This is in the spirit of [Furstenberg's use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) of the evenly spaced integer topology.

Since the $P^k, k \geq -1$ and the $U_a, a \in \Bbb{Z}$ are both bases for a topology on $\Bbb{Z}$ then the intersections of these basis elements, namely the collection of all $\{P^k \cap U_a:k \geq -1, a \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is also a basis.

Comment: Fixed the first link

Comment: Note $\displaystyle -1 \in \bigcap_{a \in \mathbb{Z}} U_a \neq \emptyset,$ so there's no hope for $U_a$ to be closed in the topology $\tau(U_a : a\in \mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.  Maybe on the subspace $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-1\}$?  I haven't thought about it

Comment: That just means that $\{-1\}$ would be a closed point, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that; rather, the closure of $\{-1\}$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}.$  To reiterate, if $U_a$ were closed for some $a,$ then since $U_a \neq \mathbb{Z}$ there must be some nonempty basic open set disjoint from $U_a.$  Since $-1$ is in the intersection of all the nonempty basic open sets, no nonempty basic open set can be disjoint from $U_a$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring answered in an edit

Comment: By your definition, P$^1$ = the set of all primes positive and negative.

Comment: @WilliamElliot yes, true.

Comment: Let $\Bbb N’=\{-1,0,1,\dots\}$ and $\rho$ be a topology on $\Bbb Z$ defined by a base $\mathcal P=\{P_j:j\in\Bbb  N’\}$. Since $\mathcal P$ consists of mutually disjoints sets, it is easy to see that a set $S$ is open in $(\Bbb Z,\rho)$ iff $S=\bigcup\{P_j:j\in A\}$ for some subset $A$ of $\Bbb N’$ iff $\Bbb Z\setminus S=\bigcup\{P_j:j\in \Bbb N’\setminus A\}$ iff  $\Bbb Z\setminus S$ is open $(\Bbb Z,\rho)$ iff $S$ is closed in in $(\Bbb Z,\rho)$. And the same holds for each subspace of the space $(\Bbb Z,\rho)$, in particular, for $\Bbb Z\setminus \{-1\}$.

Comment: Now let $\upsilon$ be a topology on $\Bbb Z$ defined by a base $\mathcal U=\{U_a:a\in\Bbb Z’\}$. Remark that $\upsilon\ne\rho$, because, for instance, $U_1\in\upsilon\setminus\rho$. The only set in $\mathcal U$ containing $0$ is $U_1$. Thus $0\in\overline{A}$ for each subset $A$ of $\Bbb Z$ such that $A\cap U_1\ne\varnothing$. In particulat, $0\in\overline{U_4}\setminus U_4$, because $3\in U_4\cap U_1$. Thus the set $U_4$ is not closed in $(\Bbb Z,\upsilon)$ (and 
$U_4\setminus\{-1\}$ is not closed in a subspace $\Bbb Z\setminus\{-1\}$ of $(\Bbb Z,\upsilon)$).